# Store single value into dynamic array: type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim Sh_Temp  As Worksheet
Set Sh_Temp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
lRow = Sh_Temp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim vArray(lRow - 1)   
vArray = Sh_Temp.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Value2  ' Exclude Header Value in A1
```

Above code works perfectly well when there is more than 1 value in worksheet 'Temp' 
but when there is only one value e.g.

```
Ref. No.
2.1.a
```

can not copy into array it gives an error

> 'type mismatch'

Comment: a Range is a 2D array like this : `ReDim vArray(1,lRow - 1)` , and `lrow-1` must never be 0 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the need for `ReDim vArray(lRow - 1)`? At `vArray = Sh_Te...` the bounds will automatically be set. Also if there is only one value, then it will just return a value and not an array. But with your `ReDim vArray(lRow - 1)` you try to insert a value in an array without a position.
You can choose to use it like this:

```
Dim Sh_Temp  As Worksheet
Set Sh_Temp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
lRow = Sh_Temp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim vArray As Variant
vArray = Sh_Temp.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Value2
```

Then `vArray` will be no array if only one value is returned, or do it like this:

```
Dim Sh_Temp As Worksheet, lRow As Long, vArray As Variant
Set Sh_Temp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
lRow = Sh_Temp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If lRow <= 2 Then
  vArray = Array()
  ReDim vArray(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
  vArray(1, 1) = Sh_Temp.Range("A2").Value2
Else
  vArray = Sh_Temp.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Value2
End If
```

then `vArray` will be a 2D-array no matter what.